# Problems in encoding when I read the txt file in C++ array in CLion

Tags: c++, encoding, clion

My program don't read the txt file correctly, I tried two ways to fix it, I changed encoding in settings and in bottom right corner of Clion, but it has not worked.
This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    ifstream in("input.txt");
    in.open("input.txt");
    int a[3][3];
    if (in.is_open()) {
        while (!in.eof()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    in >> a[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << " " << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

This is input.txt (it is in the same folder there main.cpp is):
1 4 6
23 46 99
1 5 9
This I get as an output of my program:
-858993460 -858993460 -858993460
-858993460 -858993460 -858993460
-858993460 -858993460 15016268
Process finished with exit code 0

Do you know where can be the problem?

Comment: Changing encoding settings in your IDE is not going to do *anything* regards to how your code interprets bytes in a file. You can compile the code in a different IDE or just from the command line - the same program will result, so why would you expect changing how one IDE reads files to change your program?

Comment: The input file should be in the same directory as your executable according to your code. My guess is, when you open input.txt with `ifstream`, it creates a file for you instead of opening your existing file.

Answer (score 0):

First you should test the result of operations which can fail, that help to find out the problem.  In your case, *setlocale* (I doubt that *rus* is a valid locale name) and the IO operation (you are testing the opening, but then proceed assuming that the loading correctly happen).

The issue is probably that CLion does not launch the executable from the directory you expect.  In the configuration you use, try setting the "Working directory" field to `$PROJECT_DIR$`.

Answer (score -1):

You are opening the file twice, remove `in.open("input.txt")`.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question though. The second `open()` is harmless.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Hmm, that is fair. I can't say I understand why it fails but running it locally and creating a file as mentioned by the author I see that the `in.fail()` is set if opened twice. While `in.is_open()` is still true. So I wouldn't call it harmless but it doesn't answer the question very well, that I agree on.